# Do non-linear dynamical systems have the potential to have an edge on other algorithms when it comes to computing NP-complete problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, 3-sat, physics

In a recent presentation, I've seen the difficulty of NP-complete/NP-hard problems attributed to the fact that they often have "long range" correlations, or at least they can be interpreted that way when the problem is mapped onto a physical system. For instance, in 3SAT a variable appearing in a given clause may also appear in a different clause. With increasing numbers of variables, the likelihood of variable flips having effects in many other "distant" clauses increases. This was heuristically presented as the reason why the decision trees of problems like 3SAT explode exponentially.
The point that was made is that non-linear dynamical systems admit the kind of long-range order naturally that may aid in such computations. Is this an active area of research? Are there any examples of either successful or promising attempts?

Comment: Do you have an example (link) for such a mapping to a physical system (out of curiosity)?

Comment: This statement is too vague to make an answer possible. Many people think that quantum systems are the way, so maybe they exhibit such long range correlations ?!?